# Visual Studio 2013 - Copy resource files into Output dir on each run

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in Visual Studio 2013 which is setup to copy resource files into `proj.win32/Debug.win32` directory (this is the debug build directory). The copying is being done during Pre-Link Event with the following command:

`xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\Resources" "$(OutDir)" /D /E /I /F /Y`

My question is can I do this copying on each run of the project in spite of  compilation or linking is being done. (I need this to be able to modify my resources and check on each run if I lake the new parameters).

Comment: Do you mean each run of your APP from within the IDE, or each run of the IDE?

Comment: @franji1 Each run of the app on Debug mode.

Comment: You want to copy the files every time the app runs, only in debug mode? if so you can create a script, put it somewhere like a resource of the project, have the pre-build event copy this script next to your executable (only in debug -easy using VS configuration manager) and then in your app use #ifdef DEBUG /*executae the script from code*/ #endif

Comment: No sorry for confusing. I don't need only in debug mode. Just in debug mode the Resources are being copied here: `proj.win32/Debug.win32`.